# Spoon Execute remotely doesn't work

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi, pentaho-spoon

I followed the tutorials online try to design ETL process on my local machine and upload it to slave machine for execution.

I did the following things:

1. Setting up one Slave server under "Slave server" folder
2. Right click and monitor this slave server

I can monitor the sample ktr running on my slave server which is a sign of my correct connecting with slave server

But...

3. Click *Run* arrow
4. Tick "Execute remotely", choose the created slave server as Remote host
5. "Launch"

Gets an error:

> Unable to Connect to Server
>
> You don't seem to be getting a connection to the server. Check the path you're using and make sure the server is up and running.

Which I can not understand, because I can monitor the slave server in real time.

If I tick also "Pass export to remote server" then I get another error

> HTTP Status 404 - /kettle/registerPackage/ - Not Found

```
netstat -nltp result on remote server

tcp6       0      0 :::8181                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

PS

1. I'm using PDI 6.0 Downloading from SourceForge.
2. You can reach my test carte server through:

   http://52.19.57.94:8181/

Comment: Is carte running on the remote server?

Comment: @Abercrombieande  yes verified by netstat -nltp

Comment: @Abercrombieande  updated. you can reach my test carte server. thanks a lot

Comment: I see it is running. Can you try marking it as master in the slave folder?

Comment: @Abercrombieande I ticked "is the master". The same errors

Comment: Are you sure the username and password are correct? I don't see what else it could be

Comment: I am sure they are correct (user:cluster, pass:cluster ) yep it's strange  thanks a lot for the time anyhow :)

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem. Issue turned out to be that if you are not using Pentaho Server (Enterprise), but "only" carte, you shouldn't provide anything in the Slave Server setup field "Web App Name"

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue, it turned out that I had different versions of Spoon and Carte.  Spoon v5.4 and Carte v5.3, I used Spoon v5.3 instead and it resolved both the "Unable to connect ..." and the "HTTP Status 404 ..." issue.

You're using v6 so not sure if this applies.